# Make word lowercase in C with function

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm not sure what the problem is. The function seems to be working well, but in the main function, when testing with a `printf`, it doesn't show the result.

```
char* MotMiniscule(char* mot)
{
char motm[100],c,*motf;
int i=0;
strcpy(motm,mot);
c=motm[i];
while(c!='\0')
{
    printf("%c \n",c);
    motm[i]=tolower(c);
    i++;
    c=motm[i];
}
strcpy(motf,motm);
printf("%s\n",motf);
return(motf);
}

main()
{
char *mot="HEllooOoMA",*min;
min=MotMiniscule(mot);
printf("\n le mot est %s:\n",mot);
printf("|| %s  ||",min);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you think `motf` points to?

Comment: `motf` is a pointer that hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Don't post images unless necessary. Post it as text.

Comment: `main()` returns `int`. Does your book or tutorial say otherwise? If so, replace it. Omitting the return type is a syntax error and makes your code ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

You've never allocated space for the pointer `motf` in function `MotMiniscule`:

```
strcpy(motf,motm);
```

This is undefined behavior because the address in `motf` is indeterminate. You should give it some space to point to:

```
motf = malloc(100);
```

The full code should be:

```
char* MotMiniscule(char* mot)
{
    char motm[100],c,*motf;
    int i=0;
    strcpy(motm,mot);
    c=motm[i];
    while(c!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c \n",c);
        motm[i]=tolower(c);
        i++;
        c=motm[i];
    }
    motf = malloc(100); // Allocate some memory
    strcpy(motf,motm);
    printf("%s\n",motf);
    return(motf);
}

int main()
{
    char *mot="HEllooOoMA",*min;
    min=MotMiniscule(mot);
    printf("\n le mot est %s:\n",mot);
    printf("|| %s  ||",min);
    free(min); // Don't forget to free dynamically allocated memory
}
```

As pointed out by *John Bode*, the use of `motm` is totally redundant. You can safely remove it. Besides, the size of the dymanical allocation should rely on the length of `mod`. So a refined version of the code is this.

```
char* MotMiniscule(char* mot)
{
    char c, *motf;
    int i = 0;
    c = mot[0];
    motf = malloc(strlen(mot) + 1); // Allocate some memory
    while (c != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c\n", c);
        motf[i] = tolower(c);
        i++;
        c = mot[i];
    }
    // No need to copy again, but
    motf[i] = '\0'; // Remember to terminate it
    printf("%s\n", motf);
    return(motf);
}

int main()
{
    char *mot = "HEllooOoMA", *min;
    min = MotMiniscule(mot);
    printf("\n le mot est %s:\n", mot);
    printf("|| %s  ||", min);
    free(min); // Remember to free it
}
```

Comment: And call `free(min);` at the end of `main()` to deallocate the memory. The program ends at that point and on any modern platform will be recovered in tear-down of the process but it's just bad practice to not match `malloc()` with `free()`.

Comment: Quibble - the argument to `malloc` should be based on the size of the input string, not just some random constant.

Comment: @Persixty I added it, right...?

Comment: @JohnBode The OP wrote `char motm[100]` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @iBug Yup. You did. :)

Comment: @iBug: which is just as wrong.  The size of `motf` should be `strlen( mot ) + 1`, and `motm` should be eliminated entirely - it’s redundant.

Comment: @JohnBode Useful comment, thanks. But that'd require extra changes to the code. I'll explain it in the upcoming paragraphs.

Comment: @JohnBode How does that look?

Comment: @iBug: Perfect.